# Does it matter in which ability you put a mutagen?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is the the mutagen always active, or only active when the ability with it is in use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mutagens are passive increases to character abilities. It does not matter what ability you mutate with a mutagen, as all mutagen bonuses are always active, all the time.